# Ruby on Rails Generate Data But Don't Store It

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

Hi I am new to ruby and so far have only been making simple programs that store data using scaffold so not much programming although I do know ruby I am looking to make a password api but don't want to store the password in the database or have the user input it but I do want to display it to them, I know how to generate the password because I have done this before in c++, Can anyone point me in the right direction as to where I would put this function and how I would display it. Another note is that I am also asking the user for a number so I can generate a password of the desired length so this is just standard rails scaffold currently.

EDIT:

What I am looking to do is create a password for a user dynamically generated but I don't want the user to have to input anything apart from the size and I don't want to store the password in the database. It's kind of like a one shot deal so every time you generate a password it will be different and you won't be able to see past passwords. Hope this helps clear up what I meant.

Comment: I can't really grasp what you're looking for, maybe you could rewrite this?

Comment: are you trying to reinvent something like http://strongpasswordgenerator.com/  ?

Comment: I am trying to make something like that site but my passwords are stronger that what they can generate. It's mainly just something to play with.

Comment: How are you going to make stronger paswords than `r&)l%9-T0F%+3}4ku2-%g5)]<5>?0<^6]o!x#?#"7:%*T)X?)</_4'6d|2x[,c?9@8]#100|;+:34"(M-R04)"{7=y72AR_1&I*e`

Comment: not so much with a long password like that but with shorter passwords I find there service to be inconsistent in password strength depended on the combination of letters and numbers. Short passwords can be as strong as mine but they can also be less secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your scaffold, your model does not have to be from ActiveRecord::Base.  Just make a regular ruby object that handles the logic.

If you want to validate that the user inputted a value, there are active model methods available to you.

Try one of these railscasts:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/193-tableless-model

http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model